# Proper way to use Gitflow with pull requests

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-flow

I would like to adopt the git-flow tool inside my team.

The problem is that "**git flow feature finish**" merges the branches locally.
And I want to create a pull request instead. Thus, the merge will happen in the origin.

So, what is the right way to use the git-flow tool in teams that also work with pull requests?

Tried to google it but could not find something meaningful.

Comment: Git flow isn't really a tool, it's a strategy which has extensions to help with that strategy.

Answer (score 55):

You can just use the `git flow feature publish <name>`this will publish your feature branch to your origin (like Bitbucket).  Then you can create the pull request there and merge it into develop.  After that is done, you need to manually delete the local feature branch.

The only command you can not use is `git flow feature finish <name>`.  This works fairly well and you can still use most of the git flow helpers.

The same goes for releases.  I found this article helpfull: https://blog.axosoft.com/pull-requests-gitflow/

As well as https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/git-flow-feature-finish-and-pull-request/qaq-p/347877

Hope this helps a little.  There is just not the one perfect solution to this problem.

Answer (score 4):

There is a great solution to this problem, but it does require a custom script since PR APIs are unique to each platform.

The AVH version of git-flow has some additional features:
https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh

It has support for hooks (custom scripts):
https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh/wiki/Reference:-Hooks-and-Filters#hooks

You can swap to the AVH version on a Mac using:

```
brew uninstall git-flow
brew install git-flow-avh
```

To support a pull request in git flow you can add a script:

```
.git/hooks/post-flow-feature-publish.sh
```

Example `post-flow-feature-publish.sh` script to output a url:

```
#!/bin/sh

branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
userRepo=$(git remote -v | grep fetch | awk '{print $2}' | grep "github.com" | cut -d':' -f2 | rev | cut -c5- | rev)

if [ -n "$userRepo" ]
then
    echo ""
    echo "Create PR at: https://github.com/$userRepo/compare/$branch?expand=1"
    echo ""
fi
```

Or if using the GitHub CLI you could call: `gh pr create` https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create

Now when running the command:

```
git flow feature my-feature publish
```

Git flow will push code to the feature branch and call the hook script to create the PR.

Comment: Where do you find the `post-flow-feature-publish.sh` script? It's not like most people are intimate with the Github REST API

Comment: You would need to create the`.git/hooks/post-flow-feature-publish.sh`file and add commands to create the GitHub PR. If using the GitHub CLI you should be able to call: `gh pr create` https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create

Answer (score 1):

1. Start your feature branch: `git flow feature start my-feature`
2. Develop the feature and commits related changes.
3. Publish the feature: `git flow feature publish my-feature`
4. Go to for example Gitlab and create merge-request, review and merge it (DO NOT DELETE the source/feature branch).
5. Checkout to 'develop' and pull all changes from remote origin: `git checkout develop && git pull`
6. Final step, finish the feature: `git flow feature finish my-feature`. It will be deletes 'my-feature' branch both from local and remote.